# Questionable synonyms

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

It seems that we may have some questionable synonyms.  For example:

[carnaval](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/carnaval) is a synonym for [carnival-mardi-gras](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/carnival-mardi-gras).  While [mardi-gras](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mardi-gras) may be a [carnival](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/carnival) the reverse isn't necessarily true and carnivals are not always associated with the Fat Tuesday.

Comment: A similar problem is with the football tag. Should it be used for football or soccer? I would to just make it a synonym for sports and do not care about.

Comment: Actually it should be used for both and American football and Canadian football and Australian football.  Technically it could be used for Rugby as well but I won't take it that far.  But I could see it as a synonym for [tag:sports].  We could create specific synonym to a generic but not the other way around.

Comment: Not sure about the carnaval one, but I'd be in favour of a simple [tag:sports] tag.

Comment: @MarkMayo Carnavals are not necessarily are around the Fat Tuesday and not necessarily for the same thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two different concepts. So far I believe we've only had QA on one of them:

1. There's a festival which goes by several names and several spellings which is celebrated in several ways about the same time of year in several places around the world. This tag should be **singular**, since they are manifestations of the same thing. But having more than one well-known name for the event in one tag is a good idea:

   **Carnaval/Mardi Gras**, when written as permitted by tags would become `carnaval-mardi-gras`
2. There are many small seasonal, sometimes travelling events, which are known in English as *fairs*, *funfairs*, *carnivals*, etc. These should have a **plural** tag since they are separate things. I think we could again go with a multiple name to avoid confusion:

   **Carnivals and fairs**, when written in Stack Exchange tag syntax would become `carnivals-and-fairs`.

I've noticed questions for **1.** but not for **2.** yet though it's possible I've missed some.

Variations and discussion on this theme is welcome of course.

Comment: Aren't carnivals and fairs somewhat synonymous? Otherwise this proposal seems reasonable. Basically you suggest just renaming the existing [tag:carnival-mardi-gras] to [tag:carnaval-mardi-gras], is that correct?